# Catching TCP SYNC Events

Tags: c#, .net, events, sockets

How can I catch TCP SYNC events for particular socket in .NET?

I want to be able to fire off a method which will detect if request for SFTP data transfer is made and on completion to do some action like notification or logging.

Comment: You are out of luck for your ultimate goal, there is no reliable way to determine what happens on the SFTP level by just looking at the encrypted TCP stream.

Comment: No, I don't care about actual content, I just want to know when _connection_ is established(ESTABLISHED) and when it's closed(CLOSED).

Comment: So you are just wanting to know when some other program establishes and closes a connection on port a specific port (port 22 in your specific case)? Do you want to know when your computer connects to port 22, or do you want to know when someone is connecting to port 22 on you?

Comment: Yes, I want to know when someone is connecting/disconnection on that port. I have a folder and when file is created in that folder FileSystemEventHandler fires off a method which should then check whether the connection on that port is made and after the connection is closed some other methods are called.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that the socket you want to detect the open and close of is not one your program is responsible for itself, but some other process on the system is handling it, the best way may be to use the `winpcap` library. `winpcap` allows you to subscribe to a raw feed of all IP packets coming into and going out of your network interfaces. You c an also provide a filter such as "Only show me TCP packets on port 22". Your program receives the raw packets so you get the ethernet header, followed by the IP header, followed by the TCP header, followed by the data payload (payload will be encrypted for SFTP). Analyising these packets you will be able to detect the TCP handshake on connect and know the IP and port that is connecting and detect when the TCP steam is  closed.

I don't use .NET myself, but I did find this winpcap wrapper for .NET on Google which should allow you to use `winpcap` from your .NET application.

[WinPCAP.NET Wrapper](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/)

Comment: The data you will get out of winpcap will look just like the data you get out of a Raw socket, but winpcap is just 'spying' on someone else's socket and showing you whats going on. With a Raw Socket API you are opening a socket yourself in your program and controlling it, but doing so on a packet (raw) level instead higher (stream) level. PCap is designed for watching whats going on with a socket (or manys sockets) regardless of who opened or is using them.

Comment: Hmmm...that will bind the program to .net and we plan to port it on mono.

Comment: WinPCAP.NET is just a wrapper around winpcap which can be used from any language, which is actually a port of libpcap on Linux which does the same thing. So portability should be pretty much covered using a pcap api